# regex to extract bibtex keys from \cite commands

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that extracts the bibtex keys from cite commands in a tex document. It should be able to take a complete latex document as the input string and return all the bibtex keys as matches:

```
Blahbla document
\somecommand{test} blabla nonsense lorem ipsum \cite{key1} and \cite{key2, key3, key4}
```

returns

```
key1
key2
key3
key4
```

I came up with this using https://regex101.com:

```
\\cite\{([^\},]+)(?:,\s*([^\},]+))*\}
```

It works, except for the fact that only key2 and key4 are identified as matches in the second \cite command.

Can anyone explain what goes wrong here and how it should be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: because `*` is greedy which matches all the character as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do do continuous string match, you need to use `\G` anchor.

```
(?:\\cite\{|(?<!^)\G),?\s*([^,}]+)
```

OR

```
(?:\\cite\{|(?<!^)\G),?\s*([^,}]+)(?=[^}]*})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qO7rQ1/1)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using python. Both solutions fail in that case... What makes python behave differently?

Comment: @jkokorian always include the tag of the lang you're running at very first. re module won't support `\G` anchor,. You need to use regex module.