# parsing a tex file for natbib bibtex keys using regex

Tags: python, regex, bibtex

I have a tex file and want to match all bibtex keys (using python). Unlike in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210305/regex-to-extract-bibtex-keys-from-cite-commands), they might be nested, like in the last citeation command:

```
Text \cite{AAuthor} and text \citet{Bauthor}, or \cite{CAuthor,DAuthor}, more text \cite[e.g.,][Fig. 12]{EAuthor}.
Text \citealp{FAuthor}, \citep[][see also \citealp{GAuthor,HAuthor}]{IAuthor}.
```

I only got so far:

```
\\cite[(p)(alp)(t)]*(?:\[.*\])*({.*?})
```

which misses `{GAuthor}`. How can I match all, or even better, how can I get matches like

```
HAuthor
IAuthor
```

Instead of my brackets

```
{HAuthor,IAuthor}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the "nested" cites are swallowed by the match for the outer cite and are not checked by the same pass of the matcher. What you can do, though, is to capture the part within `[]`, too, and recursively apply the regular expression to that. Something like this:

```
P = re.compile(r"\cite(?:p|alp|t)?(\[.*\])*{(.*?)}")
def match_nested_cites(text):
    for nested, cites in P.findall(text):
        for cite in match_nested_cites(nested):
            yield cite
        for cite in cites.split(","):
            yield cite

for cite in match_nested_cites(text):
    print cite
```

Output for your text:

```
>>> list(match_nested_cites(text))
['AAuthor', 'Bauthor', 'CAuthor', 'DAuthor', 'EAuthor', 'FAuthor', 'GAuthor', 'HAuthor', 'IAuthor']
```